# HighCharts: Category values are repeated. Tooltip not showing the correct date

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scatter-plot

I am plotting a scatter plot using highchart.js.

X-Axis: "Servers" [List of Servers "17.0.0.1","17.0.0.2","17.0.0.3","17.0.0.4".
Y-Axis: "DateTime" {last 5 days with interval of 6 hours}

Basically the servers gets refreshed multiple time on a given day and the data is captured and saved into database.
The chart will read the database table data and paints the chart.

Now, for shake of simplicity, i have hard-coded and showing here.

Here is the link for the JSBIN.
http://jsbin.com/joxacen/2/edit?js,output

1. The categories, "17.0.0.3" and "17.0.0.4" are repeated. I don't want this to be repeated. How to solve this? Please find the image for the repeated values.
2. The following dates are not painted for the server 17.0.0.1 
   ['Server 17.0.0.1',   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 2, 20, 0, 0)], //not painted june 2nd
   ['Server 17.0.0.1',   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 4, 11, 0, 0)], //not painted june 4th
3. Tooltip is showing some junk data. Ideally it should show me the date.

[image: Repeated values are encircled here]

Comment: I would suggest sending the category array index as the x value, not the category value:  http://jsbin.com/fuhopeqeva/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your series data array contains the servers in that order (with repeating). So it overrides the `xAxis.categories` setting. To do this with predefined categories change your x-value entry in your data array to the index of the server in the category you want:

```
series: [{
  name: 'In-Correct Server Refresh',
  color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
  data: [
         [0,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 2, 10, 0, 0)],
         [0,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 2, 20, 0, 0)], //not painted june 2nd
         [1,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 4, 10, 0, 0)],
         [0,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 4, 11, 0, 0)], //not painted june 4th
         [2,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 4, 17, 0, 0)],
         [3,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 4, 11, 30, 0)],
         [3,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 4, 12, 0, 0)]
        ]   
}, {
  name: 'Correct Server Refresh',
  color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
  data: [
         [1,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 3, 5, 0, 0)],
         [1,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 3, 12, 0, 0)],
         [1,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 3, 17, 0, 0)],
         [0,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 5, 18, 0, 0)],
         [2,   Date.UTC(2016,  5, 5, 18, 0, 0)]
        ]
}]
```

The issue with your tooltip is that you have your properties in an invalid location under `plotOptions`. It would need to be inside the `plotOptions.scatter` or at root of chart object. See this example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/eyq0f1sz/). I am not sure why you are appending the `%` symbol after your server's IP but there you go.

Comment: thanks. Accepted your answer. Yes % is not required , its a mistake. http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/eyq0f1sz/

Comment: it may help somebody. here is an example of additional data along with x and y on tooltip. http://jsbin.com/joxacen/5/edit?html,js,output